# What's the difference between Tk() and tk?

Tags: python, tkinter

For example:

```
window = tk.Tk()
```

And,

```
root = Tk()
```

I'm somehow confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is dependent on how you're importing and if you're importing only specific components from a module or the entire module.

To more specifically address your question, `tk` is the name you have given the module, and `Tk()` is the `class` inside that module that you are instantiating.

Read more in the [Official Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
```

```
from tkinter import Tk
window = Tk()
```

Comment: _"Tk() is the method"_ I dont think it is a method, I think it is a class that your instantiating

Comment: `Tk` is a class: look [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2237) @CoolCloud.